# When does "solve and plugin" fail?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, variational-principle, constrained-dynamics, optimization

In Lagrangian mechanics, sometimes some symmetry is implicit, and we perform variation on the Lagrangian and find the conserved quantity, e.g. conservation of angular momentum in a central field.

Then one may want to plugin the solution into the Lagrangian but then one will obtain a wrong equation of motion. But this can be done safely with Hamiltonian mechanics. (c.f. Routhian mechanics http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routhian_mechanics)

However, in optimization problems, which are very much similar to classical mechanics, there exists a duality (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_(optimization)).

Usually, people solve the primal optimization problem and then plug in the solution to the primal Lagrangian to obtain the dual Lagrangian.

Why is it valid in this case?